# B2C custom UI based,on parameter

Tags: user-interface, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Perhaps I am missing something but here is my problem.

Say I create multiple containers for custom UI.

```
https://your-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/container1/customize-ui.html
https://your-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/container2/customize-ui.html
...
https://your-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/containerN/customize-ui.html
```

then i define in custom policy extension file the following

```
<ContentDefinitions>
        <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
          <LoadUri>https://your-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/templates/{oauth-kv:containerName}/customize-ui.html</LoadUri>
          <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
          <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.0.0</DataUri>
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
          </Metadata>
        </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
```

when parameter is passed say '**containerName=container1**' all is good and my UI looks like the one defined by files from container1

```
https://your-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/templates/container1/customize-ui.html
```

but if parameter is not specified i want to use some default container say 'default', is there a way to do that?

as of now if parameter is not specified i get error since the resulting url would look like this:

```
https://your-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/templates//customize-ui.html
```

having '**//**' is a culprit.

anyone had to deal with similar challenge? am i approaching it entirely wrong?

thank you

Mark

Comment: Follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#sending-query-string-parameters). Try the query param method, rather than the path.

Comment: is not this what i do,  in my policy i define a query parameter and that is what I pass    

<ContentDefinitionParameters>
         <Parameter Name="containerName">{oauth-kv:containerName}</Parameter>  
      </ContentDefinitionParameters>

Comment: No: “ In your content definition, change the value of LoadUri to https://<app_name>.azurewebsites.net/home/unified. “ don’t put a claims resolver in the loadURI.

Comment: Jas, here is what I am trying to accomplish. I have many clients that are using the same app, each client has a unique id and this is my parameter. so based on that parameter (the same application) i want to change the UI if client wants to.  Use of app_name which is OIDC:ClientID will not help since app is shared by many clients.

Comment: Example in my link shows how you pass multiple query params, including custom query params.

Comment: Jas,  example in that link is exactly what I am doing - using additional query parameter. I am just asking if that query parameter is not specified i want to use default container instead of '//'  which is an invalid url.  where is the disconnect between what you suggesting and what i am asking? can you please be more patient and explain in details. thank you

Comment: The difference is the example does not use a claims resolver within the path. It states one path and the rest is managed by query parameters. This means the path will always resolve and never ends up with //. It should look like this `https://your-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/templates/customize-ui.html`. You need to move off of using a storage account and use a web app to serve the request and rely on query parameters instead. If you must use a claims resolver within the path, then you must ensure your application sends the parameter.